# How to generate an RSS feed of recently changed pages in MediaWiki?

Tags: rss, mediawiki, wiki

I am looking to create (or find) a RSS feed of recently changed pages. special:RecentChanges&feed=rss is close to what I need but it returns links to the summary of changes, not links to the actual page that has been changed. I need a feed that has the addresses of the actual pages as the value for 'link'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get is as RSS, however the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) can return what you want, e.g. like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&generator=recentchanges&format=jsonfm).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the API can do that? Thanks!